# Checking whether a sys.argv path exists

Tags: python

I am currently facing a problem in which I run a python script via cmd in which I set some of the arguments required for functions on that script also in cmd. So, I have been using sys.argv. To better explain, I would type the following:

```
python script.py arg.yaml C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents
```

So, the sys.argv are the a yaml file and the second one a path. Please note that the second one is a optional argument, so the user might not choose to add that. My goal is to raise an error if the given path doesn't exist.

I have been try the following:

```
try:
    export_path = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        try:
            Path('export_path').is_dir()            
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(custom_message_error)
except IndexError:
    export_path = None
```

But the program is still proceeding and I am not been able to catch the error. So, how would be possible to check whether or not the sys.argv path folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused some concepts here. [`pathlib.Path.is_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) does not throw an exception if the directory was not found but simply returns `False`. Moreover, you should not put your variable `export_path` in quotes when passing it to `Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path
export_path = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents"
if Path(export_path).is_dir():
    print("Path exists!")
else:
    print("Path does not exist")
```